# finding a node that does not contain maximum number of children in n-ary tree in java

Tags: java

I have trouble with a recursive function. Each node in the tree can have maximum three children.

This is the implementation of node structure. (Node class is nested class in tree class)

```
public final class Node<E> {
    private Node<E> parent;
    private List<Node<E>> children;
    private E value;
    private int maxChildren;

    public Node(int k, E value) {
        parent = null;
        children = new ArrayList<>();
        this.value = value;
        maxChildren = k;
    }

    public Node<E> findNode(Node<E> node) {
        /* find the first node without 3 children */

        if (node.numchildren() != arity) { /* arity is 3 in this case */
            return node;
        } else {
            newchildren = reverse(node.children); /* reverse because I want to scan from right to left */
            for (Node temp : newchildren) {
                return findNode(temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is, I'm trying to find the node with minimum depth(closest to root), rightmost node that does not have 3 children. But the way I implemented it above, it will check through nodes in the 'postorder traversal' way.

For example, 
[tree example] = 
in this tree, the method aims to return n3, because n3 has the minimum depth(1), and is rightmost among the nodes that satisfy the condition. 
However, with the code above, I think it will return node n7, because it traverses from n4 to n7, instead of n4 to n3. 
Can someone help me find the solution ?

Comment: I tried to include an image of  example tree, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the link to the image. 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn3AG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I can't see your image, but if you want to traverse from right to left, the easiest will be to change your for loop to start at the end index and go backwards, i.e.:

```
public Node<E> findNode(Node<E> node) {
    /* find the first node without 3 children */

    if (node.numchildren() != arity) { 
        return node;
    } else {
        List<Node<E>> newchildren = node.children; 
        for (int i = newchildren.size(); i > 0; i--) {
            return findNode(newchildren.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```